# How to make WinForms application completely ignore any kind of DPI settings?

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms, dpi

I have WinForms application written in VB .NET that "explodes" on non default DPI settings. This applications uses some ActiveX controls that just don't work with scaling.

I'm kindly asking you not to suggest me to rewrite it, move it to WPF and this kind of advices. I am fully aware that this application is bad, really bad. My job is just to make it "work".

**Is there any way to make it so that application ignores completely any DPI setting?** Any solution is good one as long as it works.

Comment: Did you manged to get a solution? i tried app manifest and dpiAware, but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to your manifest file should do the trick:

```
 <asmv3:windowsSettings 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
       <dpiAware>false</dpiAware>   
 </asmv3:windowsSettings>
```

Comment: i have tried, both dpiAware false and true, but it's still windows scaling my app and makes is look bad :( any idea?

Comment: Perhaps consider doing both this setting in app manifest file together with setting winform property AutoScaleMode == None.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the executable -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Check "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings".
(Might be slighly different on Windows version other than 10.)
This did it for me for legacy applications that "explode".

Comment: Does not work on Windows 7. This is completly ignored.

Comment: An application has no means to ignore this setting, Window 7 or not. Are you sure you're doing this on the right executable? If you start your application and go to Task Manager... Open File Location and do this setting on *that* exe, is it still ignored?

Comment: Yes I do. I even read others having same problem (with no answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `AutoScaleMode` to `None` for automatic scaling. You probably also have to 'scale' the font. This can be done by adding the following before `InitializeComponent`

```
Font = new Font(Font.Name, Font.Size * 96f / CreateGraphics().DpiX, Font.Style, Font.Unit, Font.GdiCharSet, Font.GdiVerticalFont);
```

I don't know how the hosted ActiveX control responds to these settings. Please let me know when you tried.

Comment: Setting AutoScaleMode for forms is somehow ignored.